# What does one call author blurbs at the bottom of journalistic articles?

Tags: non-fiction, business-writing, terminology, journalism

Sometimes journalistic articles have a brief about-the-author sort of blurb at the end, frequently italicized, of a general form resembling:

*J. Random Hacker is a dog groomer for the United States National Security Agency. He likes eggs.*

How does one most properly refer to these?

Comment: That could also be their job title, the example that you wrote would most likely appear in a satire magazine

Comment: The blurb may include a title, but I believe the question is asking what the whole block of text is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe they are called 'tag lines'. according to this article https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-an-article-byline-1078265

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Could you edit the relevant information from the article into your answer? As it stands, this is a link-only answer, and those are frowned upon as links tend to die out over time.

Comment: -1. As it currently stands, this is not a useful answer if I have to click on an external link to check whether your "belief" is correct. I'm happy to reverse my vote if you [edit] your answer as F1Krazy suggests. For further guidance, see [answer]. I can also recommend taking the **[Tour]**.

Comment: I disagree with the previous comments. This answer does suggest an answer to the question: that those author blurbs are called "tag lines". It's not necessary to follow the link to find (or understand) that information. That said, that doesn't *necessarily* make this a *good* answer, or even a *correct* answer. Compare [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/157730) on [meta.se].

Answer (score 4):

That would be the "author bio"

Here are some links that may be of use:
http://www.rachellegardner.com/2011/07/how-to-write-a-terrific-author-bio/
http://www.absolutewrite.com/freelance_writing/bio.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are many great jargon terms for these things. At one publication we called any such blurb an "excuse" (pronounced as the word that means 'why something happened,' not 'excuse me')

Answer (score 0):

Another word for them is "bylines"

Comment: I thought it was byline too, but the [dictionary definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/byline) just says a byline shows the author's name. It's unclear whether it includes any additional info.

Comment: bylines also characteristically occur at the top of the piece, not the bottom